# Terminal error with passing parameters

Tags: javascript, command-line, complexity-theory, plato

[Plato](https://github.com/jsoverson/plato) is a JS code complexity analyzer.

The documentation can be found at that link. I cannot get it to run however. It must be a dumb mistake but here is what I have tried.

```
plato fileX.js -d somename "~/Desktop/"
plato addNewDocPopup.js -d "~/Desktop/"
```

Amongst many others :) I don't claim to be amazing at the command line but the error I get is:
`Must specify a value for option d (dir : The output directory)`

I could have sworn that is exactly what I'm doing... Maybe not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess but maybe options must come before target file? `plato -d  ~/Desktop fileX.js`. Also, don't put `~/Desktop` in double quotes. That will prevent the shell from expanding the `~` into the path to your home directory for you.

Comment: Genuis! Thanks, not sure why i didnt think of that!